# I have an error or a missing part of my output for R code

Tags: r

I'm currently coding in R. My code so far is:

```
data = data.frame(
  route = rep(c(1, 2, 3, 4), each = 5),
  day = rep(1:5, times = 4),
  time = c(22,26,25,25,31,25,27,28,26,29,26,29,33,30,33,26,28,27,30,30)
)

model = aov(time ~ route + day + Error(route * day), data = data)
```

The output is:

```
> summary(model)
Error: route
      Df Sum Sq Mean Sq
route  1  27.04   27.04

Error: day
    Df Sum Sq Mean Sq
day  1  60.03   60.03

Error: route:day
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
Residuals  1  0.845   0.845               

Error: Within
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
Residuals 16  65.29   4.081
```

It's missing a value under Pr(>F). How would I go about getting the value? Any help appreciated.

I believe there are no errors with variable names, and have checked the parenthesis several times.

Comment: What exactly is the hypothesis you are trying to test? It's very odd to see `route` and `day` as both predictors and in the `Error()` term. Seem to just have one observations per route per day so there's no variability there which makes it tough to perform any sort of statistical analysis. Maybe you need statistical advice first from [stats.se] before you ask your programming questions.

Comment: Have a look at `summaryModel <- summary(model); str(summaryModel)`. Why those values are "`NA`" has a purely statistical reason. Btw, I think your modeling approach is non-sense.